# flyway - Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1

Tags: flyway

I have initial sql script (V1__init_schema.sql) which has syntax errors and flyway execution got failed.
When I corrected the same sql script and rerun my spring boot project. It is giving below error:

```
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: 
Validate failed: Detected failed migration to version 1
```

So, flyway doesn't rerun the failed migration scripts? Do I need to provide the corrected sql file as V2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should evaluate `flyway repair` to tell the flyway that you have fixed the issue and then run `flyway migrate`.